# How to change data source for column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table with data columns defined like this:

```
var table = myEl.DataTable({
    paging: false,
    searching: true,
    info: false,
    ordering: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    columns: [
        {data: 'Name', name: 'Name'},
        {data: 'Time', name: 'Time'}
    ]

});
```

The data that feed this table look like this:

```
 {
     Name: "Bob",
     Time: "Wed Aug 26 2015 16:09:52 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)",
     TimeTwo: "16:09:52"
 }
```

So DataTables stores the entire object and displays Name and Time.

How can I switch the data source as defined in "columns" in initialization to using `TimeTwo` rather than `Time`? (after the table gets data fed into it)

Simply: The table loads Name and Time, but how can I switch it to using `TimeTwo` after initialization? Switch it dynamically?

```
function switchDataSourceForTime(){
    // what to do...?
}
```

Comment: Use {data: 'TimeTwo', name: 'TimeTwo'} instead of Time, perhaps

Comment: That's pre init, not after init. I know I can initialize the data differently, but I'm asking about after init

Comment: Could you explain better what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean switching it dynamically? Like on a button click or some other event?

Comment: Yes, I would like to dynamically switch the source from Time to TimeTwo, with for example a button click. I'll update the question to include clearing this up.

Comment: You might create two columns and just show/hide as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make both columns are rendered but only one is shown. Something like this:

```
<div>
    Toggle column: 
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="change column value"></input>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <table id="table"></table>
</div>
```

---

```
var data = 
    [
    {
         Name: "Bob",
         Time: "Wed Aug 26 2015 16:09:52 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)",
         TimeTwo: "16:09:52"
     },
        {
         Name: "Tom",
         Time: "Wed Aug 25 2015 17:41:23 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)",
         TimeTwo: "17:41:23"
     }
];

var table = $("#table").DataTable({
    data: data,
    paging: false,
    searching: true,
    info: false,
    ordering: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    columns: [
        {data: 'Name', name: 'Name'},
        {data: 'Time', name: 'Time'},
        {data: 'TimeTwo', name: 'TimeTwo'}
    ]

});

table.column("2").visible(false);

$('#btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var columnTimeTwo = table.column("2").visible(!table.column("2").visible());
    var columnTime    = table.column("1").visible(!table.column("1").visible());

});
```

You can see the code running on [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/z8sxsjy7/3/)

Comment: This kinda does the trick. I was hoping at modifying the pointer, but it just might do. I'll test it in my code and try it probably accept tomorrow.